# What is the difference between these implementations?

Tags: python, flask, async-await, generator

In a bigger flask application, some routes stream its response. But the underlying service implementation is an async generator, so it needs to be converted to a synchronous one. Like so.

```py
from typing import AsyncGenerator, Generator
import flask
from api.routes.utils import async_generator_to_sync
import json
import asyncio

app = flask.Flask(__name__)


def async_generator_to_sync(generator: AsyncGenerator) -> Generator:
    try:
        while True:
            yield asyncio.run(anext(generator), debug=True)  # type: ignore
    except StopAsyncIteration:
        return


async def streaming_service() -> AsyncGenerator[dict, dict]:
    for i in range(3):
        yield {"task": f"task {i}"}

    yield {"done": True}


@app.route("/works")
def this_yields_all_updates_and_response():

    service = async_generator_to_sync(streaming_service())

    for s in service:
        yield json.dumps(s) + "\n"

    return flask.Response(service)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And this works. But in the bigger picture, It would be really useful to be able to structure it like this, so I can do the conversion to a normal generator in a custom route decorator.

```py
@app.route("/doesnotwork")
def only_yields_once():

    async def streaming_service_wrapper():
        async for i in streaming_service():
            yield json.dumps(i) + "\n"

    service = async_generator_to_sync(streaming_service_wrapper())

    return flask.Response(service)
```

But this does not work, it only streams the first update. To me these implementations should behave exactly the same. This is my cURL output

```bash
(base) pepijnvanderklei@pepijns-mbp Kayoc % curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/works
{"task": "task 0"}
{"task": "task 1"}
{"task": "task 2"}
{"done": true}
(base) pepijnvanderklei@pepijns-mbp Kayoc % curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/doesnotwork
{"task": "task 0"}
```

Help me out! :)